# Add custom content to certain WooCommerce email notifications for all non-USA orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm trying to add custom content (2 sentences) after the order table on the WooCommerce

- On-Hold
- Processing Order
- Order Completed

customer emails notifications.

This for **all non-USA orders**. I tried to get this result by using the `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` hook.

Here is my initial code but not sure how to make it work.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'NoneUS_custom_content_email', 10, 4  );
function NoneUS_custom_content_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( ! ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id || 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) || 'customer_on_hold_order'  == $email->id)) return;
 
    if (strtolower($woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()) != 'US') { {
        echo '<p><strong>Note:</strong> custom content.</p>';
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$woocommerce` is undefined in your attempt, You can obtain the necessary information via the `$order` object

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_email_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Target certain email notifications
    if ( in_array( $email->id, array( 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order' ) ) ) {
        if ( $order->get_shipping_country() != 'US' ) {
            echo '<p><strong>Note:</strong> custom content.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
```